# jQuery Full Calendar Events are not loading from Database in PHP,Codeigniter3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I implemented jQuery Full Calendar, as a separate module...That time it worked good. Now I want to show events after user logged in...User Login done... But issue with loading events only, events are added into Database.. But they won't be loaded into Calendar view

To redirect load.php, I used echo site_url('controller/method'),redirect('controller/method'). When I used redirect method it gives me 'json' data(the data which returned from load.php)

```
**views/calendar_view.php:**

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable:true,
            header:{
                left:'prev,next today',
                center:'title',
                right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
        events:'<?php echo site_url('Home/load'); ?>',  /* redirect('Home/load');//<?php //$this->load->view('load')?>*/
            selectable:true,
            selectHelper:true,

**views/load.php:**

if($conn==false)
 {
     echo "Failed to connect to the Database | <br/>";
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
 }

$timezone = new DateTimeZone("UTC");

$sql = "select * from events";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

if($stmt == false)
{
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
      $data[] = array(
                  'id'    => $row['id'],
                  'title' => $row['title'],
                  'start' => $row['start_event']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                  'end'   => $row['end_event']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
             );
}
```

I want to show events, after employee logged in successfully

Answer (score 0):

It looks like views/load.php does not return anything, the jquery plugin expects a json object, so add the following to load.php

```php
echo json_encode($data);
```

Furthermore as I remember the events in the plugin does not allow url's directly.
Therefore you will need to load the data from the url. Did not test it, but should be something like below.

```
$.get('<?php echo site_url('Home/load'); ?>', function(data) {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable:true,
            header:{
                left:'prev,next today',
                center:'title',
                right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
        events:data.parseJSON(),
            selectable:true,
            selectHelper:true,
});
```

You can check in your browser developer tools if the data was loaded correctly:
F.e. Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference

Comment: Sorry, because I already added "echo json_encode($data);", while copying script to here it is missed

Comment: while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
      $data[] = array(
                  'id'    => $row['id'],
                  'title' => $row['title'],
                  'start' => $row['start_event']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                  'end'   => $row['end_event']->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
             );
}

echo json_encode($data);